# If I want code to allow all the sub domains what should I do?

Tags: ruby, exit

Ruby code:

```rb
halt 403 unless url.host == 'xyz.webserver.com'
```

there are many sub domains like xyz. What is the solution if I would like to allow all the sub domains.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
halt 403 unless url.host == 'xyz.webserver.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use String#end_with?

```
halt 403 unless url.host.end_with?('.webserver.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `case`:

```
case url.host
when /\.webserver\.com\z/i
  halt 403
end
```

Where that's case-insensitive (`/i`) and allows you to add other rules as necessary.